# How to use onclick event in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to apply `onclick` event in `Selenium Webdriver` in `Java`. I am only having below code through which i can make `onclick` event in `selenium webdriver`.
Below is the `HTML` code:

```
"<a onclick="javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');" href="#">"
```

Want to perform `onclick` event using above code in `selenium webdriver`.

Comment: where is code ?

Comment: <a onclick="javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');" href="#">

Comment: Do you want to perform click on this element??

Comment: Yes.I want to click on that element @SaurabhGaur

Comment: @SonamShah then follow below provided answer by Andersson..thanks

Comment: If you have many  same kind of element (id is dynamic in your case).Please add some more `html` you having below and above the given link.

Comment: <a onclick="javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');" href="#"> <span class="label label-default"> Delete </span> </a> @NarendraRajput

Comment: just update atleast 10-15 line code( below and above your element) in your question so It will provide the clear idea how your element is present in your page. Its hard to analyze by one line code

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code sample to trigger `onclick` event:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[onclick^='javascript: confirmDelete']")).click();
```

Same with `XPath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'javascript: confirmDelete')]")).click();
```

If there is few more elements that provided selector could match, try to select required element by its index:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'javascript: confirmDelete')]")).get(n).click();
```

where `n` is an index (count starts from `0`) of target element

In case `UUID` of entry you want to delete is constant and already known:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='javascript: confirmDelete(\'442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856\');']")).click();
```

P. S. Next time instead of asking for a complete solution, first check the basics of [`Java` + `Seelenium`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)  and try to write your own code

Comment: InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[starts-with(@onclick, 'javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: As id is different in each entry so I need to pass Id. Because without id how it will find that it needs to delete particular entry only?

Comment: You have to use exactly the same selector as in example. Is there more than one link that triggers `JS` `confirmDelete()` function execution?

Comment: Also tried with "driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[onclick^='javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');']")).click();" but  same issue.

Comment: Don't use `id` inside selector! Use just `"a[onclick^='javascript: confirmDelete']"`. That's all. Do not add `id`

Comment: Yes there is more than one link that triggers JS confirmDelete().

Comment: Ok. If so show some ancestors (bigger piece of `HTML`) of target element

Comment: There are more than 67 records and in that in delete button the path you shown is same in all 67 records just id is changing for every records.This will remain the same in all 67 records : "a[onclick^='javascript: confirmDelete']"

Comment: <a onclick="javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');" href="#">
<span class="label label-default"> Delete </span>
</a>

Comment: To the very next button below is the code: <a onclick="javascript: confirmDelete('919a3a36-067f-4723-b61a-13b66141b772');" href="#">
<span class="label label-default"> Delete </span>
</a>

Comment: If it's suitable to use element's index, check updated answer

Comment: unable to use element's index

Comment: ok. try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@onclick='javascript: confirmDelete(\'442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856\');']")).click();`

Comment: Tried.Following error occur:-Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //a[@onclick='javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@onclick='javascript: confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Yep, this is because of multiple quotes. try this one `driver.findElement(By.xpath('//a[@onclick="javascript: confirmDelete(\'442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856\');"]')‌​).click();`

Comment: Invalid character constant Error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to execute `JavaScript` in `Java`:

```
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("confirmDelete('442d2c9d-fc20-4a35-8d15-22bb8f412856');");
```

Comment: What are you trying to say? What are you suggesting?